# Failed to install php-amqplib(RabbitMQ) using composer

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm trying to use this library. [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib).

`composer require php-amqplib/php-amqplib`

But I am getting this error:

```
Using version ^2.11@dev for php-amqplib/php-amqplib
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
    - Installation request for php-amqplib/php-amqplib ^2.11@dev -> satisfiable by php-amqplib/php-amqplib[2.11.x-dev, v2.11.0].
    - Can only install one of: phpseclib/phpseclib[2.0.x-dev, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: phpseclib/phpseclib[dev-master, 2.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: phpseclib/phpseclib[2.0.x-dev, dev-master].
    - Conclusion: install phpseclib/phpseclib 2.0.x-dev
    - Installation request for phpseclib/phpseclib dev-master -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[dev-master].
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve this myself. By adding

```
 "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.6"
```

in require section in composer.json and run `composer update`

Comment: With your solution, I also solved my problem. Thank you!